# Looking for testnet coins

Tags: testnet

Having a hard time getting the amount of testnet coins I need. Anyone know a way of getting a rather large amount of testnet coins?

If you can spare some:mvhTdSXUhs812vY5t1StAKohwid5GwALgK

Answer (score 0):

Ditto. I found this and am trying to implement it.

Apparently, you create a private testnet with low difficulty. I guess I'll go to lunch, because it apparently takes about an hour to do my "genesis block."

https://github.com/freewil/bitcoin-testnet-box

Be clear to stay away from the SourceForge one! Its instructions are out of date.